# Angular2 Filter Array of Objects with pipe using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-pipe

After hours of searching on stackoverflow and google I did not find what I was searching, I did find something that gave me an idea for an alternative solution.

**Object example:**

```
items = [
{
    title: "This is title", 
    email: "test@test.com",
    status: "confirmed"
},
{
    title: "This another one", 
    email: "someone@something.com",
    status: "pending"
{    
    title: "Just a random string", 
    email: "me@you.co.uk",
    status: "pending"
{    
]
```

**The resolution:**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(args == '') { return value; }

    let query = args.toLowerCase();
    return value.filter(task =>
      task.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1 ||
      task.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1 ||
      task.status.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1 

    );
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="item of (items | filter:'this is') ">
   {{item | json}}
 </div>
```

This will give me:

```
{title: "This is title", email: "test@test.com",status: "confirmed"}
```

It works as is, but my intention was to make it work with RegExp, I have tried but for some reason I got an error when I used var something = new RegExp(// some rule).

Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Something to new is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

// Tell Angular2 we're creating a Pipe with TypeScript decorators
@Pipe({
  name: 'RegexPipe'
})
export class RegexPipe {

  transform(value, args?) {
    // ES6 array destructuring
    let [pattern] = args;
    return value.filter(task => {
        reg = new Regex(pattern);
        found = reg.test(task.title);
      return found;
    });
  }

}

<div *ngFor="item of (items | RegexPipe:'/this is (.)*/') ">
   {{item | json}}
 </div>
```